# How to change the default language for the App Store Connect and the Google Play Console?

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-deliver, fastlane-supply

In my Flutter project, I'm using Fastlane to deploy my app:

- on the App Store Connect using the `deliver` command
- on the Google Play Console using the `supply` command.

My app is currently available in French only (`fr-FR`) but now I made it available in both French and English (`en-US`).

I setup all my metadata for both iOS and Android so I get all the texts and screenshots available in both French and English, but I'm stuck with one last problem: How to set English as the default language for both stores for users whose devices are set neither in French nor in English?

The documentation for both [deliver](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/) and [supply](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/) (especially `supply`) is not clear for me.

**EDIT** : I can easily change the default language manually in the Google Play Store so it's no longer a problem. But I'm still stuck with Apple that doesn't allow me to even change the default language manually in the App Store Connect...

**EDIT 2** : I also tried the following command: `fastlane run produce language:"English"`, but it has no effect, I got the answer: `App 'com.myapp' already exists (1666123456), nothing to do on App Store Connect`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for the App Store Connect:

- click on "Add a new version" at the top left
- update the primary language and save

After that, I was still able to run my CI (using Fastlane) with the same version number I entered in the first step.